# How to infer the type of a derived class in base class?

Tags: c#, generics, type-inference

I want to create a method that allows me to change arbitrary properties of classes that derive from my base class, the result should look like this: `SetPropertyValue("size.height", 50);` – where `size` is a property of my derived class and `height` is a property of `size`.

I'm almost done with my implementation but there's one final obstacle that I want to solve before moving on, to describe this I will first have to explain my implementation a bit:

- Properties that can be modified are decorated with an attribute
- There's a method in my base class that searches for all derived classes and their decorated properties
- For each property I generate a "property modifier", a class that contains 2 delegates: one to set and one to get the value of the property.
- Property Modifiers are stored in a dictionary, with the name of the property as key
- In my base class, there is another dictionary that contains all property-modifier-dictionaries, with the Type of the respective class as key.

What the `SetPropertyValue` method does is this:

- Get the correct property-modifier-dictionary, using the concrete type of the derived class (<- yet to solve)
- Get the property modifier of the property to change (e.g. of the property `size`)
- Use the get or set delegate to modify the property's value

Some example code to clarify further:

```
private static Dictionary<RuntimeTypeHandle, object> EditableTypes; //property-modifier-dictionary

protected void SetPropertyValue<T>(EditablePropertyMap<T> map, string property, object value) {
  var property = map[property]; // get the property modifier
  property.Set((T)this, value); // use the set delegate (encapsulated in a method)
}
```

In the above code, `T` is the Type of the actual (derived) class. I need this type for the get/set delegates. The problem is how to get the `EditablePropertyMap<T>` when I don't know what T is.

My current (ugly) solution is to pass the map in an overriden virtual method in the derived class:

```
public override void SetPropertyValue(string property, object value) {
  base.SetPropertyValue((EditablePropertyMap<ExampleType>)EditableTypes[typeof(ExampleType)], property, value);
}
```

What this does is: get the correct dictionary containing the property modifiers of this class using the class's type, cast it to the appropiate type and pass it to the `SetPropertyValue` method.

I want to get rid of the `SetPropertyValue` method in my derived class (since there are a lot of derived classes), but don't know yet how to accomplish that. I cannot just make a virtual `GetEditablePropertyMap<T>` method because I cannot infer a concrete type for T then. I also cannot acces my dictionary directly with a type and retrieve an `EditablePropertyMap<T>` from it because I cannot cast to it from `object` in the base class, since again I do not know `T`.

I found some neat tricks to infere types (e.g. by adding a dummy `T` parameter), but cannot apply them to my specific problem. I'd highly appreciate any suggestions you may have for me.

EDIT:
Although this is already a wall of text, I have to add some more notes:

- Performance is important. I can (and do) use reflection *once* on startup to build my dictionary and the delegates, but during runtime it's not acceptable (unless you can convince me that it is as fast as a delegate/method call ;)
- I store the `EditablePropertyMap`s as objects because I found no other way (different generic type parameters) – perhaps this can be refined as well.
- I cannot use the Curiously recurring template pattern as Mehrdad suggested. My base class cannot be generic for other reasons (has nothing to do with the problem at hand).

To clarify what `EditableProperty` / `EditablePropertyMap` does:

```
public class EditableProperty<T> {
  private Func<T, object> getter;
  private Action<T, object> setter;
  ...
  public object Get(T obj) {  return getter(obj); }
  public void Set(T obj, object value) { setter(obj, value);}
```

The map is a mere wrapper for a `Dictionary<string, EditableProperty<T>>`.

Comment: It's been a while since I read up on WPF, but isn't this something Attached Properties takes care?

Comment: This is actually a server applictaion, `size.height` was merely an example.

Comment: How does `EditableProperty<T>` work? Maybe you could make it non-generic and use `Reflection.Emit` to create the delegates?

Comment: `EditableProperty<T>` contains the get and set delegate. The delegates directly invoke the respective get / set methods of the property, e.g. the get-part of the `height` property. Therefore, they (and as a direct consequence, `EditableProperty`) cannot be non-generic. I don't know `Reflection.Emit` – is it fast?

Comment: You are re-inventing the *dynamic* keyword.  By the time perf will be acceptable, you will also have re-invented the DLR.  Avoid that.

Comment: @Hans Could you elaborate? I am trying to create methods that allow me to modify the value of strictly typed properties, known at compile time. How is this similar to the _dynamic_ keyword? I'm not very familar with it but I don't see how it would solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype.aspx - have a map of EditablePropertyMaps keyed by Type, in SetPropertyValue get the map for the derived type by GetType(). Am I missing something?

Additionally:

```
public abstract class EditablePropertyMap { }
public class EditablePropertyMap<T> : EditablePropertyMap { }
```

Edit: I guess I was poorly suggesting to just ditch the generics and pass just objects, but now I see you want to keep the delegates generic. How about the following - I rearranged some stuff but it doesn't change the gist:

```
abstract class EditableProperty { }

class EditableProperty<T> : EditableProperty {
    public void Set(T obj, object value) { Console.WriteLine(value); }
}

abstract class EditablePropertyMap {
    private static Dictionary<Type, EditablePropertyMap> maps = new Dictionary<Type, EditablePropertyMap>();

    abstract public void AddProperty(string name, EditableProperty property);
    abstract public void SetPropertyValue(object obj, string name, object value);

    static public EditablePropertyMap Get(Type t) {
        EditablePropertyMap map;

        if(!maps.TryGetValue(t, out map)) {
            map = (EditablePropertyMap)Activator.CreateInstance(
                typeof(EditablePropertyMap<>)
                    .MakeGenericType(t));

            maps.Add(t, map);
        }

        return map;
    }
}

class EditablePropertyMap<T> : EditablePropertyMap {
    private Dictionary<string, EditableProperty<T>> properties = new Dictionary<string, EditableProperty<T>>();

    public override void AddProperty(string name, EditableProperty property) {
        properties.Add(name, (EditableProperty<T>)property);
    }

    public override void SetPropertyValue(object obj, string name, object value) {
        EditableProperty<T> property = properties[name];
        property.Set((T)obj, value);
    }
}

class DynamicObjectBase {
    public void SetPropertyValue(string name, object value) {
        EditablePropertyMap map = EditablePropertyMap.Get(GetType());
        map.SetPropertyValue(this, name, value);
    }
}

class SomeDynamicObject : DynamicObjectBase {

}

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        EditablePropertyMap map = EditablePropertyMap.Get(typeof(SomeDynamicObject));
        map.AddProperty("wut", new EditableProperty<SomeDynamicObject>());

        SomeDynamicObject o = new SomeDynamicObject();
        o.SetPropertyValue("wut", 1);
    }
}
```

I also didn't do the part of making the EditableProperties from just a type at init, but I assume you've already done all that anyway.

Comment: Well, yes you are. As i said I need the generic type parameter of `EditablePropertyMap<T>`, because the get/set delegates require that exact type as parameter. I can't use `EditablePropertyMap` (without Type parameter). I know I can get the type of the derived class with `GetType()`, but what I also need is to get that type for the type parameter (`<T>`), so I can cast to `EditablePropertyMap<DerivedClass>`.

Comment: I think I get you now - new to posting here so I dunno if you get updates about answer edits, so I'll just leave a comment to make sure :)

Comment: Thank you, this is what I've been looking for. I don't have to know the type of the derived class if I encapsulate the generic properties in the map. Funny how long you can think about a problem and overlook the obvious...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you'd like a design change this big, but I think the [curiously recurring template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) may be what you need:

```
class Super<TDerived> where TDerived : Super<TDerived>
{
    //Now we have access to TDerived here
}

class Derived : Super<Derived> { ... }
```

You could also try saying something like:

```
typeof(MyClass).GetMethod("SetPropertyValue")
    .MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { derivedType })
        .Invoke(dictionary, object[] { map, property, value });
```

but this would be insanely slow.

You can't do this quickly without knowing the type at compile-time, because by definition, you have to bind the methods at compile-time in order to avoid a runtime hit.

Comment: Maybe. However, in order for TDerived to be anything but Object, it needs type restrictions, the most logical being that it derives from Super, and/or it implements some interface like `IExposePropertyDelegates`.

Comment: Ah yes I knew I forgot to mention something ;) This is not possible. I will edit my original post to clarify why

Comment: Hm... what exactly is `EditablePropertyMap`? Does it need to be generic? Could you post a snippet of it?

Comment: `EditablePropertyMap` is more or less just a convenience class, it is basically a wrapper for `Dictionary<string, EditableProperty<T>>`. `EditableProperty` (and thus the map) has to be generic in order for the delegates to work properly.

Comment: Huh, okay... I can't think of any better solution but there might be one, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are casting from your base class to your derived class anyway (in `SetPropertyValue`), why not put the cast in the generated modifier delegates? Then `SetPropertyValue` would not need to be generic any more.

As a side-note, I know you said performance is critical but have you profiled using e.g. cached `PropertyInfo` instances to do the getting and setting?

Comment: The modifier delegates are stored in the Dictionary I need to cast. (`EditablePropertyMap<ExampleType>`). I don't have access to them until I have the Dictionary, and I need to provide the concrete type for the delegates (and thus the dictionary) to use them.

Comment: I see now that you're actually talking about the method in the base class. That one still needs to be generic because the Map and Property classes are – and without type parameter, I wouldn't even know the concrete type in the Property class.